# Screenshot several regions of the screen and save them with PyAutoGui - Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, screenshot, python-3.4, pyautogui

I am a beginner in python programmation and I have a problem with screenshot function from PyAutoGui.

Here is my code:

```
#Libraries
import pyautogui, os

#Work Directory
os.chdir('C:/Users/mypath')

#Data and Variables:
ListOfNames=['T1.png','T2.png','T3.png']

#list of desired positions to screenshot:
Several_Regions=[(760, 142, 22, 23),(692, 352, 19, 21),(553, 456, 19, 21)]

#Program:  
for name in ListOfNames:
    for LeftTopWidthHeight in Several_Regions:
        pyautogui.screenshot('%s'%(name), region = LeftTopWidthHeight)
```

This is supposed to take a screenshot of each regions I mentionned
in the list of regions **Several_Regions** in three *.png* files.

But it create 3 *.png* files with exactly **the same region** taken in
screenshot **that is the 3rd** (and last) region *(553, 456, 19, 21)*...

Photo:

[image: The 3 same files]

Did I have forgot something somewhere? Please, help me to solve this problem **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in the **nested** `for` loops you actually make **nine screenshots**. And for every file, you save the third one: the last region. Because in the nested for loops you will actually make screenshots with parameters:

- `ListOfNames[0],Several_Regions[0]`,
- `ListOfNames[0],Several_Regions[1]`,
- `ListOfNames[0],Several_Regions[2]`,
- `ListOfNames[1],Several_Regions[0]`,
- `ListOfNames[1],Several_Regions[1]`,
- `ListOfNames[1],Several_Regions[2]`,
- `ListOfNames[2],Several_Regions[0]`,
- `ListOfNames[2],Several_Regions[1]`, and
- `ListOfNames[2],Several_Regions[2]`.

So as you can see, for every `ListOfNames`, the last one with which you call that is `Several_Regions[2]`.

You can however use a `zip` to make sure the first region is saved to the first file name, etc.:

```
for name,LeftTopWidthHeight in zip(ListOfNames,Several_Regions):
    pyautogui.screenshot('%s'%(name), region = LeftTopWidthHeight)
```

Given however the names you show here are *quite uniform*, you can *drop* the `ListOfNames` and use `enumerate(..)` instead:

```
for idx,LeftTopWidthHeight in enumerate(Several_Regions):
    pyautogui.screenshot('T%s.png'%idx, region = LeftTopWidthHeight)
```